# How to avoid memcached to cache a web page when an application error occurs?

Tags: caching, memcached, cache-control, memcachedb

me and my team are getting mad over this.

We perform full-page caching on the webpages of our website. 
Everythings works fine, but when an application error occurs memcached starts caching blank pages, then served to end users until they expire.

Does anyone know if there is any memcached configuration parameter that can help us in avoiding this? Does anyone know about any other trick?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: We need more information. What's performing the caching? Django/Rails/something else? Code that you wrote yourself? Be more specific :)

Comment: Hi and thanks! The error occurs when we per form full-page cache on not logged-in users. We check if a user is not logged i and, in this case we either geerate the cache page or we request it (in case it is present). Or application works on PHP+Zend framework.